# Catch invalid input and return to input prompt JAVA

Tags: java

I am very new to Java and as part of my college course I have to write a program that carries out some basic functions. Part of this program is that it needs to calculate the factorial of a number that the user inputs. If the user inputs a negative number then it must prompt for a positive number. I have got it to do this.

But if the user enters a fraction such as 2.2 then the program should present the user with an error and prompt for valid data. I believe some sort or try-catch should be implemented but so far I have had no success in getting this to work, after spending many hours on it. Any ideas how to get the program to catch the InputMismatchException error and prompt user for input again?

The relevant block of code from the program is below...

```
public static void factorialNumber() {
    int factorial = 1;
    boolean valid;
    int number = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        number = sc.nextInt();
        valid = number > 0;
        if (!valid) {
            System.out.println("ERROR Please enter a positive number");
        }
    } while (!valid);

    if (number < 0) {
        System.out.println("***Error***: Please enter a positive number ... ");
        factorialNumber();
    }

    if (number > 0) {
        System.out.print("The factorial is: " + number + " ");
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        factorial *= i;
        if ((number - i) > 0) {
            System.out.print("x " + (number - i) + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("= " + factorial);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Double` class to parse the user input and then get only correct values. Like this:

```
public static void factorialNumber() {
    int factorial = 1;
    boolean valid;
    int number = 0;
    String userInput;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        userInput = sc.nextLine();
        valid = validateUserInput(userInput);
    } while (!valid);

    number = Double.valueOf(userInput).intValue();
    System.out.print("The factorial is: " + number + " ");

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        factorial *= i;
        if ((number - i) > 0) {
            System.out.print("x " + (number - i) + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("= " + factorial);
}

private static boolean validateUserInput(String userInput) {
    if (userInput == null) {
        System.out.println("You should enter a number!");
        return false;
    }

    Double userInputNumber;
    try {
        userInputNumber = Double.valueOf(userInput);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid number value.");
        return false;
    }

    if (userInputNumber <= 0) {
        System.out.println("ERROR Please enter a positive number");
        return false;
    } else if (userInputNumber - userInputNumber.intValue() > 0) {
        System.out.println("ERROR You entered a fractional number!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```